# if $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges almost surely to $Y$ then $aX_n+bY_n$ converges almost surely to $aX+bY$

Tags: probability-theory

Let be $X_n$ and $Y_n$ successions of random variables and let be $X$ and $Y$ random variables.
Show that if $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges almost surely to $Y$ then $aX_n+bY_n$ converges almost surely to $aX+bY$.
I tried in this way:
Call A:={$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n=X$} and B:={$\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n=Y$}. Then P(A)=P(B)=1, and it is easy to see that $P(A\cap B)=1$. But on $A\cap B$ we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} aX_n+bY_n=aX+bY$, thus P{$\lim_{n \to \infty} aX_n+bY_n=aX+bY$}$\geq P(A\cap B)=1$ and we have the thesis. is it right?

Comment: Looks good to me, yes.

Comment: do you have another way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be the underlying probability space.
Since $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ a.s. and $Y_{n}\rightarrow Y$ a.s., there
exist $\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2}\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(\Omega_{1})=P(\Omega_{2})=1$
such that: for each $\omega\in\Omega_{1}$, $X_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow X(\omega)$,
and for each $\omega\in\Omega_{2}$, $Y_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow Y(\omega)$.
Define $\Omega_{\ast}=\Omega_{1}\cap\Omega_{2}$, then $P(\Omega_{\ast})=1$
(note that $\Omega_{\ast}^{c}=\Omega_{1}^{c}\cup\Omega_{2}^{c}$,
which has measure zero because it is the union of two measure-zero
sets). Now, for any $\omega\in\Omega_{\ast}$, $aX_{n}(\omega)+bY_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow aX(\omega)+bY(\omega$).
That is, $aX_{n}+bY_{n}\rightarrow aX+bY$ a.s.